# Calculate the limit: $\lim_{x\rightarrow1^{+}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt{x-1}} \right )$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, functions, convergence-divergence

> Calculate the limit:
>   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow1^{+}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt{x-1}} \right
> )$$

I used L'Hôpital's rule because without we end up with "$\frac{0}{0}$"...

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1^{+}}\left(\frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-1}}}\right)= \lim_{x\rightarrow1^{+}}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{x-1}}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)=\lim_{x\rightarrow1^{+}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x}}\right)=\frac{1-1}{1}=0$$

Thus the function converges?

Is all correct?

Comment: Yes, you did correctly.

Comment: I'm glad I did it right this time, thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Your approach (and result) are correct.*

For reference, here is an other easy approach, based on [Taylor approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions). (Quite detailed below). You can rewrite $\sqrt{x}-1=\sqrt{1+(x-1)}-1$. Now, since $x-1 \to0$, we can use a first-order Taylor series to get:
$$
\sqrt{1+(x-1)}-1 = \left(1+\frac{x-1}{2}+o(x-1)\right) - 1
= \frac{x-1}{2}+o(x-1)
$$
where the $o(\cdot)$ is the [Landau notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) *(meaning "negligible in front of")*, here when $x\to 1$.

Going back to the original fraction, this leads to
$$
\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt{x-1}}
= \frac{\frac{x-1}{2}+o(x-1)}{\sqrt{x-1}}
= \frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{2}+o(\sqrt{x-1})\xrightarrow[x\to1]{}0
$$

Comment: Note that the above also quantifies the *rate* of convergence to zero: the quantity behaves like $\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{2}$ when $x\to 1^+$.

Comment: +1 for using the Peano form of the remainder!  It is a form that seems to be neglected even though it is extremely powerful.  So, well done Clement. -Mark

Answer (score 4):

Expand with $\sqrt{x}+1$ to get the fraction
$$
\frac{(x-1)}{(\sqrt{x}+1)\sqrt{x-1}}=\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{(\sqrt{x}+1)}
$$
So yes, the result is $0$.

Comment: Maybe worth also mentioning that the OP's approach is correct (besides getting the right result -- one can get the right answer with faulty arguments).